# Can I rotate a 3D object in ARCore without using ARFragment?

Tags: android, 3d, arcore, sceneform

I am working on a simple Android app using `Sceneform` in which I have to rotate a 3D object when a user taps on it. I know I can do it in `ArFragment`, but I don't want to use Augmented Reality for this purpose. I am simply using `Sceneform` as a 3D viewer and the only interaction user needs is to tap the display in order to rotate the model. Is it possible in `ARCore` without using its Augmented Reality shenanigans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is! You should use only the `SceneView` component in your layout instead of the `<fragment...` block and from this point, everything is the same as with ArFragment. 
About the rotation: You still can use the `TransformableNode` (https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode) if you want, it's not tied to the ArFragment or you could implement a basic rotation on tap:

```
node.setOnTapListener { hitTestResult, motionEvent ->
   node.localRotation = Quaternion.multiply(node.localRotation, Quaternion(Vector3.up(), 180f))
}
```

This would rotate your node by 180 degree.

Comment: Yes, this method totally works. The only nuance is I have to write my own rotation controller for drag gesture-based rotation since by default, only the twist gesture works for rotation. Thanks!